# No import suggestion for node_modules referenced in tsconfig paths

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a `core` package shared between multiple microservices using the following `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "paths": {
         "core/*": [ "./*" ],
         "*": [
            "*",
            "../microservices/service1/node_modules/*",
         ]
      }
    },
}
```

Microservices uses the following `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig-base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
         "core/*": [
            "../../core/*",
         ]
      }
    },
    "references": [
      { "path": "../../core" }
    ]
}
```

And the root directory uses references in the `tsconfig.json` like so:

```json
{
    "files": [],
    "references": [
      {
         "path": "./core"
      },
      {
         "path": "./microservices/service1"
      }
    ]
}
```

- When I try to import the `core` package from a microservice like `import { sharedVal } from "core/shared";`. It works but I have no import suggestion in VSCode.
- When I try to import microserives packages from core like `import { useState } from 'react';` it works if I add `"../microservices/service1/node_modules/@types/*"` to `paths` but still no import suggestion

Here is a repro repo: https://github.com/MathieuUrstein/monorepo-repro

Comment: For the first point, my issue is the following: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39778